# How to stop dynamically added menu items in a Navigation Drawer from always going to the top?

Tags: android, android-design-library

I'm trying to add menu items dynamically to my navigation drawer.  When I add the dynamic menu items, they always appear at the very top of the navigation drawer.  That's not where I want them.

This is how I am adding the dynamic items:

```
mNavigationView.getMenu().add(R.id.nav_list, Menu.NONE, Menu.NONE, "Item1");
mNavigationView.getMenu().add(R.id.nav_list, Menu.NONE, Menu.NONE, "Item2");
mNavigationView.getMenu().add(R.id.nav_list, Menu.NONE, Menu.NONE, "Item3");
mNavigationView.getMenu().add(R.id.nav_list, Menu.NONE, Menu.NONE, "Item4");
```

I would like these dynamically added menu items to be part of the second group of items in my navigation drawer.  Here is the XML to my drawer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group
        android:checkableBehavior="single"
        android:orderInCategory="100">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="Camera" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="Gallery" />
    </group>

    <item
        android:orderInCategory="700"
        android:title="Dynamic Options Here">
        <menu>
            <group
                android:id="@+id/nav_list"
                android:orderInCategory="200" />
        </menu>
    </item>

    <item
        android:orderInCategory="800"
        android:title="Settings">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_dev_settings"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
                android:title="Device Settings" />

            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_personal_settings"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
                android:title="Personal Settings" />
        </menu>
    </item>

    <item
        android:checkableBehavior="single"
        android:orderInCategory="999"
        android:title="Other">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_help"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
                android:title="Help" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_about"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
                android:title="About" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

When I use this code, the dynamic menu items always appear at the very top of the navigation drawer and everything else is below it.  The order is maintained with everything else.  Also the title "Dynamic Options Here" is missing.

I'd like the dynamic group to appear after the gallery icon in its own group (with the horizontal line above and below the group) and I'd like the group title "Dynamic Options Here" to appear.

Answer (score 0):

In class Menu has:

```
public MenuItem add(int groupId, int itemId, int order, CharSequence title);
```

You can try:

```
mNavigationView.getMenu().add(R.id.nav_list, Menu.NONE, 0, "Item1");
mNavigationView.getMenu().add(R.id.nav_list, Menu.NONE, 1, "Item2");
mNavigationView.getMenu().add(R.id.nav_list, Menu.NONE, 2, "Item3");
mNavigationView.getMenu().add(R.id.nav_list, Menu.NONE, 3, "Item4");
```

or

```
 mNavigationView.getMenu().add(R.id.nav_list, Menu.NONE, 3, "Item1");
 mNavigationView.getMenu().add(R.id.nav_list, Menu.NONE, 2, "Item2");
 mNavigationView.getMenu().add(R.id.nav_list, Menu.NONE, 1, "Item3");
 mNavigationView.getMenu().add(R.id.nav_list, Menu.NONE, 0, "Item4");
```

Comment: Eek, maybe I wasn't clear.  It's not that the order is wrong within the group of dynamic items, it's that the entire group is being moved to the top as soon as I add a dynamic item.  I want the groups to stay in order.